# Flot Graph visitors per day

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I am new to angular-js and need to achieve below mentioned functionality.
I have a graph with full data, while selecting particular area of this graph, another graph should show the selected data details w.r.t selected area graph.

for code refrenece, please check link: [Code in MS Drive](http://1drv.ms/1vUKnrN)

While selecting the below graph top graph is changing accordinginly.
 http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working after specifying the height of the container divs (this is necessary, see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#introduction)). See the snippet:

```js
     $(function() {

       var d = [
         [1196463600000, 0],
         [1196550000000, 0],
         [1196636400000, 0],
         [1196722800000, 77],
         [1196809200000, 3636],
         [1196895600000, 3575],
         [1196982000000, 2736],
         [1197068400000, 1086],
         [1197154800000, 676],
         [1197241200000, 1205],
         [1197327600000, 906],
         [1197414000000, 710],
         [1197500400000, 639],
         [1197586800000, 540],
         [1197673200000, 435],
         [1197759600000, 301],
         [1197846000000, 575],
         [1197932400000, 481],
         [1198018800000, 591],
         [1198105200000, 608],
         [1198191600000, 459],
         [1198278000000, 234],
         [1198364400000, 1352],
         [1198450800000, 686],
         [1198537200000, 279],
         [1198623600000, 449],
         [1198710000000, 468],
         [1198796400000, 392],
         [1198882800000, 282],
         [1198969200000, 208],
         [1199055600000, 229],
         [1199142000000, 177],
         [1199228400000, 374],
         [1199314800000, 436],
         [1199401200000, 404],
         [1199487600000, 253],
         [1199574000000, 218],
         [1199660400000, 476],
         [1199746800000, 462],
         [1199833200000, 448],
         [1199919600000, 442],
         [1200006000000, 403],
         [1200092400000, 204],
         [1200178800000, 194],
         [1200265200000, 327],
         [1200351600000, 374],
         [1200438000000, 507],
         [1200524400000, 546],
         [1200610800000, 482],
         [1200697200000, 283],
         [1200783600000, 221],
         [1200870000000, 483],
         [1200956400000, 523],
         [1201042800000, 528],
         [1201129200000, 483],
         [1201215600000, 452],
         [1201302000000, 270],
         [1201388400000, 222],
         [1201474800000, 439],
         [1201561200000, 559],
         [1201647600000, 521],
         [1201734000000, 477],
         [1201820400000, 442],
         [1201906800000, 252],
         [1201993200000, 236],
         [1202079600000, 525],
         [1202166000000, 477],
         [1202252400000, 386],
         [1202338800000, 409],
         [1202425200000, 408],
         [1202511600000, 237],
         [1202598000000, 193],
         [1202684400000, 357],
         [1202770800000, 414],
         [1202857200000, 393],
         [1202943600000, 353],
         [1203030000000, 364],
         [1203116400000, 215],
         [1203202800000, 214],
         [1203289200000, 356],
         [1203375600000, 399],
         [1203462000000, 334],
         [1203548400000, 348],
         [1203634800000, 243],
         [1203721200000, 126],
         [1203807600000, 157],
         [1203894000000, 288]
       ];

       // first correct the timestamps - they are recorded as the daily
       // midnights in UTC+0100, but Flot always displays dates in UTC
       // so we have to add one hour to hit the midnights in the plot

       for (var i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
         d[i][0] += 60 * 60 * 1000;
       }

       // helper for returning the weekends in a period

       function weekendAreas(axes) {

         var markings = [],
           d = new Date(axes.xaxis.min);

         // go to the first Saturday

         d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - ((d.getUTCDay() + 1) % 7))
         d.setUTCSeconds(0);
         d.setUTCMinutes(0);
         d.setUTCHours(0);

         var i = d.getTime();

         // when we don't set yaxis, the rectangle automatically
         // extends to infinity upwards and downwards

         do {
           markings.push({
             xaxis: {
               from: i,
               to: i + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
             }
           });
           i += 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
         } while (i < axes.xaxis.max);

         return markings;
       }

       var options = {
         series: {
           bars: {
             show: true,
             lineWidth: 1,
             barWidth: 5,
             fill: true
           },
           shadowSize: 0
         },
         xaxis: {
           mode: "time",
           tickLength: 5
         },
         selection: {
           mode: "x"
         },
         grid: {
           markings: weekendAreas
         }
       };

       var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [d], options);

       var overview = $.plot("#overview", [d], {
         series: {
           bars: {
             show: true,
             lineWidth: 3
           },
           shadowSize: 0
         },
         xaxis: {
           ticks: [],
           mode: "time"
         },
         yaxis: {
           ticks: [],
           min: 0,
           autoscaleMargin: 0.1
         },
         selection: {
           mode: "x"
         }
       });

       // now connect the two

       $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function(event, ranges) {

         // do the zooming
         $.each(plot.getXAxes(), function(_, axis) {
           var opts = axis.options;
           opts.min = ranges.xaxis.from;
           opts.max = ranges.xaxis.to;
         });
         plot.setupGrid();
         plot.draw();
         plot.clearSelection();

         // don't fire event on the overview to prevent eternal loop

         overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
       });

       $("#overview").bind("plotselected", function(event, ranges) {
         plot.setSelection(ranges);
       });

       // Add the Flot version string to the footer

       $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");

       // Set default

       overview.setSelection({
         xaxis: {
           from: 1203289200000,
           to: 1203894000000
         }
       });


     });
```

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <h2>Visitors</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">

  <div class="demo-container">
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="height:150px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="demo-container">
    <div id="overview" class="demo-placeholder" style="height:150px;"></div>
  </div>

  <p>This plot shows visitors per day to the Flot homepage, with weekends colored.</p>

  <p>The smaller plot is linked to the main plot, so it acts as an overview. Try dragging a selection on either plot, and watch the behavior of the other.</p>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  Copyright &copy; 2007 - 2014 IOLA and Ole Laursen
</div>
```